# Generating set of $M_2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1) Can $S = \{ A \in M_2 (\mathbb R) \mid \det(A) \ne 0 \}$ be a generating set of $M_2(R)$?
And .
My second question is most important for me
2) if  $G = \{ v \in V / C (v) \}$ where $C (v)$ is condition of set $G$ followed by  $v$.  As  in above question $C (A) = \det (A) \ne 0$.
My question is - is  subspace
  $L (G)$ generated by $G$  also follow  then condition $c(v)$ of $G$. And contains only those elements which satisfies $c(v)$?

Comment: To your first question, yes.

Let's consider $M=\begin{pmatrix}p&q\\r&s\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\Bbb R)$. It can be shown that $M$ can be written as a linear combination of invertible matrices.

Consider the matrix sum,$$a\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}+d\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

where the reals $a,b,c,d$ are given by,

$$a=\frac{p+q+r-2s}3\\ b=\frac{p+q-2r+s}3\\ c=\frac{p-2q+r+s}3\\ d=\frac{-2p+q+r+s}3$$

Comment: What about 2nd ?

Comment: How is $L(G)$ defined?

Comment: V is vector space  over field F  and  G is subspace of V of all linear combination  of  of elements of G .

Comment: Oh, so $L(G)=\langle G\rangle$ is the span of $G$ ? In that case, the answer is no. This is evident from the answer of your first question. Since $S$ generates $M_2(\Bbb R)$, so we have $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\in L(S)$ but $|A|=0$

Comment: Ok , but converse is true   I think ,   converse is true  ,means  if    L (G )  satisfies any condition then   G satisfies that  as G contained in L (G) .

Comment: Generically two matrices generate $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.